# Return array with filter object at specific index in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to remove an object at index 2 and return array in computed.

I can do it in div with v-for & v-if but it some warning.

```
    <div
          v-for="(index, i) in sameImage"
          v-if="i !== 2"
        >
   </div
```

How to it in computed with filter.

```
sameImage:function () {
      
      const ar = this.MainImg;
      
      return ar.filter();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the index as the second parameter of the filter callback :

```
return ar.filter((_,i)=>i!==2);
```

or separate the `v-if` and `v-for` in different elements like :

```
<template  v-for="(index, i) in sameImage">
  <div          v-if="i !== 2">
    {{index}} 
  </div>

</template>
```

`template` is not the root one, it's a virtual element that will not be rendered in the DOM

Comment: In 1st one it showing item is declare and never used.

Comment: You could use underscore `_` instead of `item` to avoid that warning `return ar.filter((_,i)=>i!==2)`